# Unable to connect to the remote server Exception in C# when i use tiny url download method in remote server but it works in local

Tags: c#, sockets

This is my tiny url generation code

```
IPVUrl = IPVUrlBaseUrl + returntext;
CommonUtils.Log4NetWriteRequestLog(this.GetType() + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "Request DocumentUrlSend:- success1", "RxDigifinAPIRequestProcess");
System.Uri address = new System.Uri("tinyurl" + IPVUrl);
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
if (ProxyFlag == "True")
{
    WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("http://192.168.211.36:1050", true);
    client.Proxy = myProxy;
}
IPVUrl = client.DownloadString(address);
```

the above downloadstring url works in local but not working in server throws exception like

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond 104.20.57.30:80    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest&
>   request)    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)

Comment: There are three different types of errors 1) Do no have route to server 2) Port is blocked or in use 3) Credentials are not correct.  Could require a secure connection using SSL/TLS.  The exception message does not indicate which of the 3 type errors are causing issue.  So we have to start from the beginning.  First verify route is good by using cmd.exe > Ping IP (or machine name.  If ping works the use cmd.exe >Netstat -a (at host and remote machine) and check if port is listening on server and not being used by another app on client.

Comment: Ping isn't a very reliable method for determining if the network route is valid because so many firewalls and devices disable ICMP.  A better diagnostic be telnet.